# Game Center Authentication with Swift

Tags: authentication, swift, game-center, ios8

Using the following code, the `GKLocalPlayer().authenticated` variable is always `false`. Once the code runs to `"User still not authenticated"`, you are able to download Game Center data. Is this a bug or an issue with the code below?

```
func notificationReceived()
{
    println("GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName - Authentication Status: \(self.localPlayer.authenticated)")
}

//MARK: 2 Authenticate the Player
func authenticateLocalPlayer()
{
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    self.delegate?.willSignIn()

    self.localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.showAuthenticationDialogueWhenReasonable(viewController)
                })
        }

        else if (self.localPlayer.authenticated == true)
        {
                println("Player is Authenticated")
                self.registerListener()
                self.downloadCachedMatches()
                self.delegate?.didSignIn()
        }

        else
        {
            println("User Still Not Authenticated")
            self.delegate?.failedToSignIn()
        }

        if (error)
        {
            self.delegate?.failedToSignInWithError(error)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: 2a Show Authentication Dialogue
func showAuthenticationDialogueWhenReasonable(viewController:UIViewController!) -> Void
{
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The console output look like this:

```
    init(notification:)
    authenticationCheck()
    authenticateLocalPlayer()
    GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName - Authentication Status: false
    GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName - Authentication Status: false
    showAuthenticationDialogueWhenReasonable
    GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName - Authentication Status: false
    GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName - Authentication Status: false
    GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName - Authentication Status: false
    User Still Not Authenticated
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.149128 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceLogToFile="-"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.149544 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceErrorLogLevel="ALL"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.149997 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceMonitorNSLog="1"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.150429 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceStreamOutputFormat="CSV"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.150875 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceLogToFile="-"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.151312 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceErrorLogLevel="ALL"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.151768 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceMonitorNSLog="1"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.152211 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceStreamOutputFormat="CSV"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.152626 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceLogToFile="-"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.153060 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceErrorLogLevel="ALL"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.153489 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceMonitorNSLog="1"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Debug>: 07:33:10.153925 com.apple.viceroytrace: ENV: VRTraceStreamOutputFormat="CSV"
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Info>: 07:33:10.154140 com.apple.viceroytrace: [CHECKPOINT] logging-started
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Notice>: 07:33:10.154146 com.apple.viceroytrace: gVRTraceErrorLogLevel initialized to ALL (9)
    Aug  2 07:33:10 iMac.local   <Info>: 07:33:10.144097 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {
        "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
        "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
        "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
        "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Xcode 6 Beta 6 – there's now `GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()` class func which does the business.

Answer (score 1):

if you are attempting to translate the Objective-C code in the Game Center Programming Guide re: "Authenticating a Local Player" ->

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW18)

...then you're not quite following the pattern correctly

where you are using:

```
if (viewController) {
    ...
} else {
    if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

...their pattern uses:

```
if (viewController) {
    ...
} else if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

try re-writing your code using their pattern - an important item to note is where they write:

*Game Kit automatically authenticates the player asynchronously, calling your authentication handler as necessary to complete the process.*

...they don't specifically say ***when*** or ***how many times*** they attempt to authenticate - and it's all happening asynchronously anyways, I can totally imagine that it may be the case that your code, in its current form, may print to the console "User Still Not Authenticated", but that by the time some other part of your app checks they may have authenticated and be able to download Game Center data.

One more note: it may also be possible that you are seeing a situation where there is cached Game Center data... note that in the final `else` of the example's conditional branching (`if...else if... else`), they disable Game Center altogether

let me know how this turns out! I'd be interested in knowing

Comment: I've amended the code to follow the code example from Apple (behaviour is the same). Additionally, I've also included the log output which shows the output from monitoring the `GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName` notification. Any time that is posted the code prints the authentication status (always false). Interestingly, after "User still not Authenticated" the app seems to connect to Game Center anyway. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that, I create a simple class for iOS game center in GitHub
https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift

Begin

```
import GameKit
/// The local player object.
let gameCenterPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
```

After in your func

```
    self.gameCenterPlayer.authenticateHandler={(var gameCenterVC:UIViewController!, var gameCenterError:NSError!) -> Void in
        
        if gameCenterVC != nil {
            self.presentViewController(gameCenterVC, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                // no idea
            })
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue. I have the same authenticate construction. I think Apple has changed their login routine: if you become no error and no LoginViewController it means that you have successfully logged in. Since they deleted GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer attribute it could be the solution. There is one thing though - they didn't delete the GKLocalPlayer.authenticated flag and this leaves the issue unresolved.

EDIT: My assumption about changing the authentication-routine was false: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLocalPlayer/authenticateHandler

they actually use this flag to confirm the authentication. The problem remains unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode6 GM authenticated is still false.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced that issue and I solved it by enabling Sandbox mode on from setting -> Game Center -> Developer -> Sandbox.

Hope it will help someone.